enable wrap wdr-level-* rows/cells with long text
As I noticed cell height,top,etc. are calculated.
How can I change wdr-level-* cells to wrap text and set a max-width?
I tried to add cellBuilder.addClass("text-wrap") using bootstrap 5.x class but did not work.

It seems that WebDataRocks does not support wrapping text in the cells. As a workaround, consider setting bigger cells' width or using tooltips. For example, to display tooltips, you can use the following customizeCell code:
function customizeCellFunction(cellBuilder, cellData) {
    if (cellData.type == "header") {
        cellBuilder.text = `<p style="overflow: hidden; 
        text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; color: white"
        title='${cellData.label}'>${cellBuilder.text}</p>`;
    }
}

